# kylin failed to load kylin.properties

Tags: kylin

When start to Apache kylin WebUI(2.2.0 and 2.1.0) to do something, I got some error from Web console and the tools can't working correctly. But As I try to use kylin(1.6.0),This project is working.

The below text from Web console:

```
scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660 GET http://172.60.40.24:7070/kylin/api/admin/config net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660
sendReq @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8454
serverRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8174
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11820
$eval @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12863
$digest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12675
$apply @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12967
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1461
invoke @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:3979
doBootstrap @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1459
bootstrap @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1473
Request.loader.onload @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42277
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
Request @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42282
window.onload @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42286
scripts.min.20171030210304.js:10159 failed to load kylin.properties[object Object]
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:10159
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:84746
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:22844
wrappedErrback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11743
wrappedErrback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11743
wrappedErrback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11743
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11876
$eval @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12863
$digest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12675
$apply @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12967
done @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8478
completeRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8692
xhr.onreadystatechange @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8631
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660
sendReq @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8454
serverRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8174
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11820
$eval @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12863
$digest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12675
$apply @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12967
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1461
invoke @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:3979
doBootstrap @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1459
bootstrap @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1473
Request.loader.onload @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42277
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
Request @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42282
window.onload @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42286
scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660 GET http://172.60.40.24:7070/kylin/api/tables?ext=true&project=learn_kylin net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660
sendReq @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8454
serverRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8174
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11820
$eval @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12863
$digest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12675
$apply @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12967
done @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8478
completeRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8692
xhr.onreadystatechange @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8631
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660
sendReq @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8454
serverRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8174
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11820
$eval @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12863
$digest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12675
$apply @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12967
done @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8478
completeRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8692
xhr.onreadystatechange @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8631
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660
sendReq @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8454
serverRequest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8174
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
wrappedCallback @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11734
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:11820
$eval @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12863
$digest @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12675
$apply @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:12967
(anonymous) @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1461
invoke @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:3979
doBootstrap @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1459
bootstrap @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:1473
Request.loader.onload @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42277
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
Request @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42282
window.onload @ scripts.min.20171030210304.js:42286
scripts.min.20171030210304.js:8660 GET http://172.60.40.24:7070/kylin/api/models?projectName=learn_kylin net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

Someone know the problem how to solve?

[some error text from Web console.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tzKB.png)

Comment: Do you solve it? Because I experiencing the same problem, and the hive tables is not loaded in kylin, even though if I run hive shell and run "list" command there are tables from kylin/bin/sample.sh

Answer (score 0):

I had same error while starting kylin. Kylin requires java 1.8 or later. Hence first install java 1.8 if you dont have. After that verify if PATH variable is pointing to java 1.8 or later. Then try to start kylin again , it will work. all the best!